# I edited my wordpress url link to https whereas i haven't installed ssl certicate yet. my website is no longer going

Tags: wordpress

Please I need help on what to do. I edited my url directory to https from http. Now my site is no longer going again. It keeps redirecting to https but i do no have ssl certificate installed yet. What do I do now?

Comment: Revert it and get certificate first.

Answer (score 0):

There are four easy methods to change the Site URL manually. Any of these methods will work and perform much the same function. You can read the manual in the [wordpress codex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55893167/i-edited-my-wordpress-url-link-to-https-whereas-i-havent-installed-ssl-certicat) for more information

I think the safest is by editing wp-config.php. just add these tow lines:

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
```